# Meaning of "Profit"

Tags: meaning

I was asking a question about how to deal with sweat in shoes.

Some replied:

> 1. Wash.
> 2. Let them dry out.
> 3. Profit.

What does "Profit" mean here? Someone suggested it is related to South Park. I have no idea.

Comment: Was this on Slashdot?  (there was an article recently there about shoes and this is a popular Slashdot meme)

Comment: Context: http://www.styleforum.net/showthread.php?p=4162621

Comment: The South Park episode in question is [*Gnomes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomes_(South_Park) "See the Wikipedia page").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an internet meme from South Park that has no actual meaning. It is often used when listing steps to achieving a goal, usually with a step before that labelled "???" to indicate that they are not sure how to get from the existing goal to actually making money. You can find more information [here](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/profit).

Comment: Yeah, and the author of the quote used it wrong.

Comment: And incorrectly used, at that. It should have been: 1. Wash; 2. Let them dry out; 3. ?; 4. Profit. It's the mystery missing step that makes the joke (and the meme).